# how to display content of oleObject that embeded in aspose.word for c# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, ole, aspose, aspose.words

I create an workbook

```
            Document doc = new Document();
            var builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            int i = workbook.Worksheets.Add();
            Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[i];
```

and then create my cells and then  an insert it to my document by `insertOleObject` method:

```
    MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
                workbook.Save(memorystream, Aspose.Cells.SaveFormat.Xlsx);
                byte[] bytes = memorystream.ToArray();
Shape oleObject = builder.InsertOleObject(memorystream, "Excel.Sheet.2", false, null);
```

I want worksheet that i build in workbook can be shown as a table  but that does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify code as shakeel said in comment of his Answer And I accomplish :

```
 MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
            workbook.Save(memorystream, Aspose.Cells.SaveFormat.Xlsx);
            byte[] bytes = memorystream.ToArray();
            memorystream.Position = 0;
            // Apply different Image and Print options
            var options = new Aspose.Cells.Rendering.ImageOrPrintOptions
            {
                HorizontalResolution = 200,
                VerticalResolution = 200
            };
            // Set Horizontal Resolution
            // Set Vertical Resolution
            var sr = new SheetRender(sheet, options);
            MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
            sr.ToImage(0, imageStream);
            System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
            Shape oleObject = builder.InsertOleObject(memorystream, "Excel.Sheet.12", false, image);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please add one more line of code as I have shown here and it should fix your issue. Let us know your feedback.

**C#**

```
MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
workbook.Save(memorystream, Aspose.Cells.SaveFormat.Xlsx);
//Add this line
memorystream.Position = 0;
```

Here is the full runnable code for your reference.

**Title:** Insert Microsoft Excel Ole Object into Microsoft Word Document

**C#**

```
Document doc = new Document();
var builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
sheet.Cells["D3"].PutValue("This is sample data.");
sheet.Cells["J20"].PutValue("End");

MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream();
workbook.Save(memorystream, Aspose.Cells.SaveFormat.Xlsx);
memorystream.Position = 0;

Aspose.Words.Drawing.Shape shp = builder.InsertOleObject(memorystream, "Excel.Sheet.12", false, null);

doc.Save("Output.docx");
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: so thanks but still doesn't show excel sheet as a table and only show a excel object by aspose for .net icon .in this docx i must click on the icon then my workbook open but i want data table be displayed in docx.

Comment: You will have to create a worksheet image using Aspose.Cells and then create System.Drawing.Image via FromFile() or FromStream() methods and then pass it as a parameter in replace of null. i.e. The last parameter in the code is null but you should pass your own Image object. i.e. Aspose.Words.Drawing.Shape shp = builder.InsertOleObject(memorystream, "Excel.Sheet.12", false, yourImg);